# Modify the behaviour of WriteLine method?

Tags: c#, console-application, static-classes

I need a very simple to imagine thing - modify **System.Console** class method **WriteLine** to write not only in console, but also in text log file.

I simply need to run this function with preset arguments prior to any call to WriteLine and then do generic WriteLine:

```
class Logger
{
    static public void WriteLog(string logMessage, string fileName ,bool addTimeStamp = true)
    {
        //Getting temp folder
        string destPath = Path.GetTempPath();

        //Creating folder
        if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);

        //Naming log file
        var filePath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.log",
            destPath,
            fileName
            );

        //Writing to timestamp
        if (addTimeStamp)
        {
            logMessage = String.Format("[{0}] - {1}{2}",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                logMessage,
                Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            logMessage = String.Format("{0}{1}",
                logMessage,
                Environment.NewLine);
        }
        //Writing to log
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, logMessage);
    }
}
```

I thought about inheritance, but I cannot even create a class since *"Static class ConsoleX cannot derive from type Console. Static classes must derive from object"*.

Is there at all simple way to wrap around WriteLine method? I would do a separate (not inherited) class for it but then I need to create like 18 overloads for this method just to pass through arguments to 18 overloads of generic WriteLine, so it feels like waste of effort for seemingly simple thing.

Comment: Fun fact: At the IL level, a `static` class is both `abstract` and `sealed`, which is *why* it can't be instantiated or inherited.

Comment: Consider using one of the available mature logging frameworks (Serilog, log4net, ...) instead of `Console.Out`. These allow to apply all sorts of additional formatting (like adding the timestamp) and send the output to configurable targets (Console, File, Syslog, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` is equivalent to `Console.Out.WriteLine`, so you can implement your own `TextWriter` and pass it to `Console.SetOut` to achieve your purpose.

BTW a class can not inherit a static class in any way.

```
class ConsoleOut : TextWriter
{
    private TextWriter _oldOut = Console.Out;

    // This overload method is the base method of all
    // Write or WriteLine overloads.
    // But you can override other methods as you want
    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        // Write to the original console
        _oldOut.Write(buffer, index, count);
        // Write to file
        Logger.Write(buffer, index, count);
    }
}

Console.SetOut(new ConsoleOut());
```

---

BTW 2, the default console ouput is synchronized, but your method isn't, this is what you need to consider, because you may get IOException.

Comment: Thanks. It says: class does not implement inherited abstract member 'TextWriter.Encoding.get'. Also, it's not quite clear for me how to transform buffer, index and count to more higher level things like text string I feed to Logger.WriteLog?

Comment: 1. Implement `TextWriter.Encoding`, it's abstract. 2. As I wrote in the comment, _you can override other methods as you want_, e.g. `WriteLine(string)`.

Comment: This correctly answers the question, but I almost feel like it's incomplete without mentioning that substituting Console.Out is the wrong solution for the problem in the first place. You should be using a logging framework instead of writing to Console.Out directly. Then the logging framework can easily be configured to write to different outputs, using custom formatting, and even handle more complex needs like rolling to new log files each day, or when the log file reaches a given size.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, sometimes you have to redirect the console output to a log file, for instance some third party console libraries whose outputs are not under your control, this requirement is reasonable in the situation.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to create a derived class from a static class in C#. A static class is a class that cannot be instantiated and therefore cannot be inherited from. Instead, you can use a regular class or an abstract class as a base for a derived class.

Comment: While this is true, your answer does not address the problem how to modify the behaviour of `Console.WrireLine`.